# common law partner requirement

Tags: immigration, canada

Good day, My name is Abike, please assist clarify. My partner is the primary applicant for immigration application to Canada. However, is it necessary for me to verify my degree with WES to enable it boost his points?

Comment: In short yes, if you want to boost your points the degree has to be verified with WES. Express entry only considers valid WES verified degrees in order to increase your point count.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/assessment.asp) link gives all the information about verifying your degree. In short, in order to boost your points in the Comprehensive Ranking System under Express Entry, you **must** verify your degree with [WES](https://www.wes.org/ca/). Express Entry only considers degrees verified in a similar fashion to give you the points.

*Its not a compulsion to verify your degree* If you don't you just won't get the points for your education. So if you think you have enough points, then you don't need to verify your degree.

The cut off points for the Express Entry draw have been pretty low lately ranging around 450-500. So now would be a good time to apply for it.

Good Luck.